# Schema design for store billing with multiple payment providers

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, paypal, stripe-payments, telegram

***What I'm doing***

I'm writing a `Telegram` bot using `TelegrafJS` + `MongoDB`; this bot allows the user to subscribe to a private channel using three types of billing:

- PayPal
- Stripe
- Manual (when the user doesn't have any credit card, I generate manually an access code for the private channel, when the user insert the access code, a subscription is created).

The main problem here is the customer reference, in fact when I generate a subscription using `PayPal` or `Stripe` the `customer_id` is different 'cause they are different payment providers, so I have the following situation:

```
P. Provider | Customer Id | Subscription Id
   PayPal        1ac            a
   Stripe        2ac            b
```

And actually I created the following model to store the customer and the subscriptions:

**Customer Model**

```
let CustomerSchema = new Schema({
    telegram_id: Number,
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    hasTrial: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    subscriptions: [SubscriptionSchema],
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true
    }
});
```

as you can see there is the field `telegram_id`, this is valorized using the `telegram.chat.id` of the user, and allow me to manage the user in the private channel (resource that the user pays to access).

There is also the `hasTrial` field, which allow me to create a manual subscription just one time, this subscription isn't linked to any payment providers but is stored in the same way of others subscriptions:

**Subscription Model**

```
let SubscriptionSchema = new Schema({
    _id: String,
    period_start: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    period_end: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    plan_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

the main question is: how can I keep track of subscription `a` and `b` which are part of different payment providers (so different `customer_id`)?

***What I thought***

I thought to create two additional fields in the `Customer Model` as:

```
stripe_id: String
paypal_id: String
```

but I honestly don't like this solution. I need to store someway the the customer id of both payment providers 'cause the subscription status is changed via the `webhooks`, eg:

1. Stripe send `subscription.cancelled` hook to `b` subscription which is linked to `2ac` customer
2. My application set the subscription `status` as `canceled` and also kick out from the channel the user which have as `telegram_id: 5`

with the current database design I can't know which user the subscription is linked to..

Could you suggest me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how this is a problem. Any RDBMS will be able to store differently-formatted PayPal and Stripe `subscription_ids` in the same column, and do lookups of the `customer_id` for the same, using a simple SELECT query.

---

If necessary, PayPal (and perhaps also Stripe) would let you pass and receive back the customer_id, using a field like 'CUSTOM' in subscription status updates, but I would not suggest depending on this functionality in any way (except perhaps as a backup -- set the CUSTOM field on write, i.e. new subscription setup, but don't ever read it during your business logic).

Payment providers are not a database, and their data storage capabilities should not be used beyond what is necessary for efficient payment processing. You should store and retrieve IDs yourself as I mention in the first part of my answer.

Comment: The problem is that I have a customer table which contains the telegram id of the customer and the id generated by mongodb, this id isn't the `customer_id` associated to the subscription of each provider, so I should store the `customer_id` of the provider inside the `subscriptions` model, this is the only way I guess to know to which customer is linked the subscription

Comment: Your customers model should have a reference to their active subscription_id...

*and/or*, your subscriptions model should have a reference to the customer it belongs to....

Either way works, and will allow you to use a subscription_id to look up its corresponding customer_id.  Simple 1:1 relationship

Comment: I understood what you mean but you missed an important point, when the `webhook` try to add the subscription to my DB, how to know the customer linked to that subscription? The problem is still the same, I should store the reference of my customer on the payment provider system in a custom field

Comment: I don't think the problem actually exists. Assuming the data is properly stored, with a proper model, you should be able to ask your database: "here is my subscription_id, what customer_id does it belong to?" via a SELECT query, and the database should respond "it belongs to this customer_id".  You should not need a custom field.  I strongly do not recommend depending on your payment providers' custom fields for such basic functionality that your database should be doing.  Only write to such a custom field as a backup (in case of data loss) or for reporting

Comment: This: "here is my subscription_id, what customer_id does it belong to" is the problem. Initially I just have the customer with the `telegram_id`, eg: customer with `telegram_id` 5 pay for a month subscription on Stripe, then Stripe generate a new subscription for his own customer with id `abc5`, when the `webhook` is triggered on my app the customer id `abc5` doesn't exists 'cause is stored as `telegram_id`: 5.. and the app is not able to associate the Stripe subscription on my DB. Sorry if I was not so clear and thanks for your help

Comment: If the very first time you get the subscription_id, it only has a Stripe customer_id and not your own customer_id, then yes that is an issue.  But the issue is not the 1:1 association between your customer_id and subscription_ids in your database, which should be easy.  The issue is Stripe (and perhaps PayPal) isn't sending your own customer_id when they first give you the subscription_id.  So for that, a field like CUSTOM can be useful! (if there's no other way to solve the problem).  But in the future, when you get sub updates, you should already know which subid goes to which of your custid

Comment: Okay, so you suggest me to store the custom field on the payment provider?

Comment: No, if there is a way to get the subscription_id in a context where you know which customer it belongs to, I don't suggest using the CUSTOM field for that.  But if you are only being notified of new subscriptions asynchronously and without context of which customer it belongs to, then you will need a field like INVNUM or perhaps CUSTOM to tie it back to the original customer it belongs to.  When later payments on a subscription are made, you should already know which customer it belongs to, and have no need for the CUSTOM field.  But you can perhaps have it set for reporting/backup purposes.